# Eclipse creates an html file on desktop, instead of in the workspace

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on an application and I dynamically create an HTML file using Java in Eclipse. The problem is if I do not specify the path where the file will be created, eclipse creates it on desktop, instead of in the folder of my project in eclipse-workspace. Is there a way to save it in the folder without specifying the path? Thanks!

```
File f = new File("distance.html"); //creates a file on desktop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There mostly isn't; the concept of a 'workspace' is not going to be there when you run your application outside of eclipse, and eclipse is just where you write the software. It's not where you run it 'for real' - you may run it there, but only for the purposes of debugging.

However, in the run target (main menu > Run > Run Configurations...), find the run config you are using. You have the option for 'Working directoy', which is in the 'Arguments' tab.

The default **is your workspace**, you have either messed with this setting already, or something weird is going on. Set this back to your workspace (usually via `${workspace_loc:projectName}` as a value, or just.. pick 'Default' again.

`new File()` does not create anything, it's just a simple pointer to a file. However, relative paths are resolved relative to 'current working directory', which you can set with that option.